# How to reconnect mongo automatically in node.js server?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, connection

Let say I have a node.js server connecting to a mongoDB.   Then the mongoDB die or disconnect.  Of course, node.js server will lose connection.  Even if I restart mongoDB, node.js server will not connect to the new mongodb automatically even it is running on the same machine with same port.  I need to either restart Node.js server or somehow write my own routine to reconnect it.

Is there any node module to handle reconnection? and in a less aggressive way. (i.e. won't ask for connection every second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question will depend on your driver version and your specific code.

The most recent driver versions should support [connection pooling](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/commit/d8030259894c10f52e562051e8f5da2e574a5d48). This typically means that you may get an exception when attempting a first connection, but you should be able to re-connect.

Your implementation is also important. There are several ways to do this. Some people open a connection outside of starting the web server, others do it in response to requests.

If you have connection pooling, then you should be able to "open a connection" on every request. You will have to handle the errors correctly after reboot, but you should not need to restart the Node environment.

Comment: I know this thread is really old, but I have the same question.  I'm using Mongoose version 4 to connect to Mongodb and am unable to get my node app to reconnect to the mongodb server after it is brought back up.  Can you please provide a sample code about the possible ways to implement the reconnection without having to restart node every time? (I'm a newbie at this).  Thanks.