# MongoDB - check if it is connected with async and await?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, async-await

How do I check if mongodb is connected with `async` and `await`?

I tried:

```
  const db = await mongodb.connect(config.database.url)
  db.on('ready',function() {
    console.log('database connected');
  })
```

I don't get 'database connected' even the db is connected.

Any ideas?

Comment: `const db = await MongoClient.connect(config.database.url);` `MongoClient.connect()` returns a `Promise`. The `await` waits for resolution of that promise, and when that is done and the value returned then the database is connected. So don't mix promise resolution and event handlers.

Comment: If you are looking for when different events are actually fired, then [Listen to reconnect events in MongoDB driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45124993/2313887)

Answer (score -1):

If `mongodb.connect(config.database.url)` returns a Promise, you just need to put `console.log('database connected')` on the next line, because Js will hold and execution in non-blocking manner until connection is established and then continue.

Comment: how do I check `mongodb.connect(config.database.url) returns a Promise`?

Comment: The most convenient way is to check docs on `mongodb` module.