# How to catch serverOpening event?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

here is my problem. Admitting my BDD crashes for any reason, i'd like to be able to catching this event to stop my website because it depends only on my BDD.

My problem is I cannot catch when I stop mongoDB or when I restart it.

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

let __mongodbClient;

export async function getMongoDBClient() {
  if (__mongodbClient == null) {
    __mongodbClient = await MongoClient.connect(
      MONGODB_URL,
      {
        appname: 'Test',
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        ignoreUndefined: true,
        authSource: MONGODB_AUTH_SOURCE,
        auth: MONGODB_AUTH,
        poolSize: 30,
      }
    );
    console.log(__mongodbClient);
    __mongodbClient.on('serverOpening', () => {
      console.log('serverOpening');
    });
    __mongodbClient.topology.on('close', (...args) => console.log('Connection closed', args) );

    __mongodbClient.on('reconnect', () => console.log('reconnect'));
    __mongodbClient.on('serverClosed', () => console.log('server closed'));
    __mongodbClient.on('error', () => console.log('error') );
  }

  return Promise.resolve(__mongodbClient);
}
```

What is wrong with that ?
it doesn't happen anything. No error.
thx for help

Comment: Please read through this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124079/listen-to-reconnect-events-in-mongodb-driver. Apparently you need to use, __mongodbClient.server.on() and not __mongodbClient.on

Comment: Hello !
I've already tried this and I got this "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined"

Comment: Can you show me how you import MongoClient?

Comment: Sure, i'm using es2015 syntax with babel-cli and babel-preset-es2015.
I updated my post and I wrote the import method.

Comment: What I see from documentation is the events fired on  db connections are : authenticated,
close,
error,
fullsetup,
parseError,
reconnect,
timeout,      So these events should work.I dont see serverOpening event on that. And Hence error, reconnect and close events should work in your case

Comment: Could you say, which event you do not receive?

Comment: I receive no one that's the problem. Event if i let only the reconnect event i cannot catch it, nothing happens.

Comment: console.log(__mongodbClient); What is the log after connect statement? What do you get in console?

Comment: Also please see in package.json which Mongoclient version you are using. In 3.0 the connect doesn't return the db. It returns the client

Comment: @Aditya 
I'm using mongodb 3.1 !

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code with following

```
let db = _mongodbClient.db('your db name');
    db().on('serverOpening', () => {
      console.log('serverOpening');
    });

    db.on('reconnect', () => console.log('reconnect'));
    db.on('serverClosed', () => console.log('server closed'));
    db.on('error', () => console.log('error') );
```

And it should work

Comment: Hello, when I try what you wrote I got this "__mongodbClient.db.on is not a function"

Comment: Was the connection established?

Comment: As i said im using mongodb 3.1. Is this possible that the problem comes from the version of mongodb ?

Comment: I made a edit in my code. The client now returns the client and from that we can get the db specific instance to listen events on. Could you try the updated piece of code, and see if that works for you?